# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() after json_decode()

Tags: php, json

I'm Newbie with PHP. i Try insert my array to MySQL Table.
I have array like this

```
[
  {
  },
  {
  "td1":"1",
  "td2":"PENCIL",
  "td3":"3",
  "td4":"PIECES",
  "td5":"3",
  "td6":"3",
  "td7":"9",
  "td8":"<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button>"
  }
]
```

and this my PHP File

```
$myArray = json_decode($_POST['stock'],true);
    
    print_r($myArray);

    foreach($myArray as $row){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO stock(NAME, QTY, WEIGHT, UNIT, DESC) 
    VALUES (
        '" . $row["td2"] . "', 
        '" . $row["td3"] . "',
        '" . $row["td5"] . "',
        '" . $row["td4"] . "',
        '" . $row["td6"] . "'
        )";
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}
```

I get an error
`Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

I have looked for several references on this and have changed the array format to suit their examples. can you tell me where my mistake is?

Comment: Why you're deleting your questions? If you need to clarify something, simply ask in the comments. Asking irrelevant questions instead won't get you anywhere.

Comment: I can *guess* that you are creating this JSON manually while it should be produced by a **designated function**.

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid. Look at the quote marks in the bit which has html.

Comment: i created this array using a function in jquery. is my array invalid?

Comment: Yes. You have double quote marks inside a double quoted string. So how is it supposed to know where the string really ends when it's decoding it? Did you not use JSON.stringify() to generate valid JSON?

Comment: i have used, product:JSON.stringify(string) in my javascript. I think I have found the problem. it is found in "td8":"<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button>". is there a way for me to remove that element from my resulting array?

Comment: `it is found in "td8":"`...yes I know - that's what I already told you. But you can't have used JSON.stringify to produce the JSON array you've shown in your question, because that function does not generate invalid JSON. Here's a demo, converting a JS array literal into JSON - note the escaping of the quotes in the console output: https://jsfiddle.net/fr3qvchn/

Comment: `is there a way for me to remove that element from my resulting array`...well if you don't need it, then why did you put it in the array in the first place? You're not really giving us any context for your question.

Comment: I was really confused when I tried to create an array from an HTML table and got this error, I thought the error lay in my php code but finally I know how this works. Thank you for responding to my question. without your help I would not have been able to know this.